# HTML input and output

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have an Excel file that shows a table where the user changes the value of a field. When this value changes the value of another field changes automatically because it has this formula:

```
row 26 =IF(DWT<40000,11500,(11500+(0.2*(DWT-40000)))).
```

I want to publish that Excel file on the web but don't lose its interactivity. Tried to save it as an HTML but no luck, no interactivity was saved, just a static HTML. I decided to build it using Notepad++ (HTML).

Now, I'm stuck at this point: I want the user to enter a value in "1", then press OK and the result appears in "2".

Here's the code I have written so far:

User enters a value in 1:

```
<td class=xl6612603>Dwt:</td>
<td class=xl6512603>
    <form id="numform" oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)">
        <input type="number" id="a" step="any" value="a<40000,11500,(11500+(0.2*(a-40000)))">
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
        <b>Enter value and press "OK"</b>
    </form>
</td>
```

Result appears in 2:

```
<td rowspan=2 class=xl10112603 width=97 style='border-top:none;width:73pt'>
    <output form="numform" name="x" for="a"></output>
</td>
```

Where *`a`* is "DWT", as far as it concerns the math formula I wrote above.

The above code is giving me this: when user enters a value in "1" the same value appears in "2" automatically. I'm missing some things here...

Have attached an image [Shows what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TnMS.jpg)

UPDATE: Problem solved but got stuck somewhere else.

So, I want user to enter a value in field number "4" and the result to appear in field "5" and field "6".

Field "5" has this formula: field "4" * 0.1

Field "6" has a different one: field "4" * 0.05

This is the code I wrote for the field "5" but it doesn't work though I put it inside the :

```
<body>
<script>
  window.formula = function (val1) {
  var b = parseInt(val1);
  var c = 0.1;
  var d = b * c;
  return d;
 }

</script>
```

This is the code I wrote for field "4":

```
<td class=xl6612603>Gross Tonnage:</td>
<td class=xl6512603><form id="numform" oninput="y.value=formula(b.value)"> <input type="number" id="b" step="any"><input type="submit" value="OK"><b> Enter value and press "OK"</b></form></td>
```

This is the code I wrote for field "5":

```
<td rowspan=2 class=xl10112603 width=97 style='border-top:none;width:73pt'><output form="numform" name="y" for="b"></td>
```

Here's another pic that shows what I want to do

[What I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHcid.jpg)

Comment: "I want to build excel in a webpage", I'm not sure you know how crazy that is... :)

Comment: I am still looking for php part in the question.

Comment: It's the second time I'm using this site so give me a hint if I make some mistakes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't understand Excel formulas.
You need to convert 
`a<40000,11500,(11500+(0.2*(a-40000)))` to the equivalent javascript

Assuming I understood the Excel formula, the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0advLpk/) should do the trick.

Comment: It worked!!! THANK YOU so so much!!! May I ask one last question: if the user wants to enter other type of numbers besides integers, is there a way to do it ? Something like: 150,25 for example

Comment: I copied and pasted the code for the same result to appear in  the cell right next to "2" but it nor "2" appears

Comment: @Nick P For decimals, use a period (.) instead of a comma. Oninput is the important thing, it means it updates the cell (output to be precise) named x.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code for the same result to appear in the cell right next to "2" but nothing appears. Even the result in cell "2" doesn't appear...

Comment: If you want to update additional cells you'll need to do things a little differently. See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0advLpk/1/) for one way of doing it

Comment: I'm not really helping you by solving all these. You should take some time to understand how html and javascript work together. [Latest Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40eorc6m/)

Comment: You are right but I'm not familiar with javascript plus it's something I will take some time to look afterwards. I'm at the office trying to make this HTML works :-) Really appreciate the help

Comment: The problem is, when I add the second script none of the two scripts are running. I tried to put the two scripts in one <script> but only the first runs